# Trying to run an applet standalone

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

So my assignment is the following:

```
Write a Java applet to add two numbers from text fields, and displays the result in a 
non-editable text field. Enable your applet to run standalone with a main method. A 
sample run of the applet is shown in the following figure.
```

I've managed to make the applet itself, which runs within Eclipse, but when I export it as a JAR, nothing happens when I try to run it. I've re-read the (brief) section on this in my textbook a few times, and have spent the last hour or so on Google. And so here I am, asking for advice.

My code:

```
package NumberTwo;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class AddNumbers extends JApplet {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField textFieldOne;
private JTextField textFieldTwo;
private JTextField textFieldResult;

private int numberOne, numberTwo;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Applet is in the frame");
    AddNumbers applet = new AddNumbers();
    applet.init();
    applet.start();
    frame.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Create the applet.
 */
public AddNumbers() {
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    // Labels

    JLabel labelOne = new JLabel("Number 1");
    labelOne.setBounds(30, 35, 56, 16);
    getContentPane().add(labelOne);

    JLabel labelTwo = new JLabel("Number 2");
    labelTwo.setBounds(130, 35, 56, 16);
    getContentPane().add(labelTwo);

    JLabel labelResult = new JLabel("Result");
    labelResult.setBounds(230, 35, 56, 16);
    getContentPane().add(labelResult);

    JLabel labelAdd = new JLabel("Add");
    labelAdd.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            Addition();
        }
    });
    labelAdd.setBounds(164, 62, 56, 16);
    getContentPane().add(labelAdd);

    // Text Fields

    textFieldOne = new JTextField();
    textFieldOne.setBounds(90, 32, 30, 22);
    getContentPane().add(textFieldOne);
    textFieldOne.setColumns(10);

    textFieldTwo = new JTextField();
    textFieldTwo.setColumns(10);
    textFieldTwo.setBounds(190, 32, 30, 22);
    getContentPane().add(textFieldTwo);

    textFieldResult = new JTextField();
    textFieldResult.setEditable(false);
    textFieldResult.setColumns(10);
    textFieldResult.setBounds(272, 32, 30, 22);
    getContentPane().add(textFieldResult);

}

public void Addition() {
    numberOne = Integer.parseInt(textFieldOne.getText());
    numberTwo = Integer.parseInt(textFieldTwo.getText());
    textFieldResult.setText(String.valueOf(numberOne + numberTwo));
}
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the JAR?

Comment: The Windows 7 "loading circle" pops up for about a tenth of a second, and then, nothing.

Comment: After a bit more trial and error, looks like I figured it out - apparently I wasn't hitting 'Next' enough when trying to export. After doing so, I tried "Selecting the class of the application entry point" and hitting browse, and choosing the one option available. I'd take this down, but in case someone else might be having the same issue, I'll leave it. If an admin disagrees though, feel free to take it down.

Comment: You should either delete it or enter an actual answer below (then accept the answer).

Comment: Yeah, I tried to, but since my rep is below 10 it said I had wait 8 hours until after posting it to answer my own question. I'll do that now though. EDIT: And looks like I can't accept it until tomorrow, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more trial and error, looks like I figured it out - apparently I wasn't hitting 'Next' enough when trying to export. After doing so, I tried "Selecting the class of the application entry point" and hitting browse, and choosing the one option available.

I also didn't need the lines

```
applet.init();
applet.start();
```

so I omitted them as well.